# disable Focus in datagrid records items wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

hi i have a datagrid When I focus on a row and move in the rows with the keyboard Dotted around selected cells appear. you can see image below

[image]

this is my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      Background="#eceff5" RowHeaderWidth="0" AlternatingRowBackground="#fbfcfe"
                                      GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                      CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                                      CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" 
                                      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#dde8ef" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle}"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,75,10,10">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="نام" MinWidth="120" Width="auto" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

and here is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#6f7e95"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,5,7,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#7c8ca6"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                                <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                                <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#354052"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#70b8f3"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#70b8f3"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

so how i can fix this? If you see the image, you will see an additional column. How do I delete this column? Currently, the following column has been deleted by the following code, but datagrid is not fit on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the solution was setting the cell's style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="SaturdayCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
  <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Then in the `DataGrid`:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource SaturdayCellStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your style to remove the `FocusVisualStyle`.

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Shloimele, but that will only remove the focus adornment, not disallow focus or tab stop.